# Using to_char to format currency?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

So I want the salary returned in the result set to be formatted to this currency type but I believe I am using the to_char in the wrong spot but I'm not sure how.  I'm also not sure if I have to use it in both instances of Salary either.   Any help would be much appreciated!!

```
SELECT EMPNO, ENAME, JOB, SAL * 52 TO_CHAR('$999,999')
FROM EMP
WHERE SAL * 52 >
(SELECT AVG(SAL *52) FROM EMP);
```

I receive the
`ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected` error from **Oracle Apex**.

It runs fine without the `to_char`.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but: elementary arithmetic shows that your `WHERE` condition can be written more simply as `SAL > (SELECT AVG(SAL) FROM EMP)`. An employee's annual salary is greater than the average annual salary of all employees if and only if her weekly salary is greater than the average weekly salary of all employees, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to let your value in first parameter second is your format.

```
SELECT EMPNO, ENAME, JOB, to_char(SAL * 52,'$999,999')
FROM EMP
WHERE SAL*52 > (SELECT AVG(SAL * 52) FROM EMP) ;
```

Comment: Then it just gives me a column full of $999,999 which is not what I want.

Comment: @DominicDevero So do you want to let  `$999,999` to number or let number to  `$999,999` format?

Comment: I want to take the Sal * 52 column and format it to look like ($260,000 or $154,700).

Comment: @DominicDevero I see you can try to let your value in first parameter secode is your format.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the data you want formatting into to_char also:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(123, '$999,999') from dual
```

So pass your sal*52 in as the first argument

Incidentally you may want to use a format more like:

```
TO_CHAR(Sal*52, 'L999G999D99')
```

Rather than hard coding symbols and grouping separators in, using these letters will take the symbol and grouping separator from the region settings of the database. If your app will have an international audience you should appreciate that not everyone uses a comma to group thousands and a period for decimals. Some people write 123.456,99 for "one hundred twenty three thousand four hundred and fifty six [dollars] 99 [cents]" example

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions181.htm has more info on to char

Might also be worth mentioning if you're getting unexpected leading spaces after to_char()ing, start your format mask with FM eg

```
TO_CHAR(123, 'FML999G999D99')
```

FM is Fill Mode, turns off a facility in oracle that automatically pads data with leading spaces so it matches the width of the formatting mask. It's handy for reports if youre dumping data in a fixed-width format, to have it padded by spaces, so all your amounts are eg 9 characters wide, but it's unnecessary or undesirable in other contexts

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this:

```
SELECT EMPNO, ENAME, JOB, TO_CHAR(SAL * 52, 'FM999,999') as SALVAL 
FROM EMP
WHERE SAL * 52 >
(SELECT AVG(SAL *52) FROM EMP);
```